# How do I use INetFw interfaces for multiple network connections?

Tags: .net, windows-xp, firewall, windows-firewall, windows-firewall-api

Windows XP machine has wired and WiFi interfaces active concurrently. My code must manage the firewall settings only for the WiFi connection and ignore the config for the wired connection.

I'm using the INetFw interfaces from C#. I am able to enumerate open ports and services like this...

```
    INetFwMgr manager = GetFirewallManager();
    INetFwPolicy policy = manager.LocalPolicy;
    INetFwProfile profile = policy.CurrentProfile;

    foreach (INetFwOpenPort p in profile.GloballyOpenPorts)...
    foreach (INetFwService s in services)...
        foreach (INetFwOpenPort p in s.GloballyOpenPorts)
```

When I add Exceptions in Control Panel for all connections, I see them from my code. But Exceptions added for a specific connection in the Control Panel Advanced tab are not visible to my code.

I can't see how to ensure that the holes in the wired connection are not open in the WiFi connection. I want to only open a few ports on the WiFi connection.

Am I missing something in the INetFw APIs to select which connection I want to manage?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer...

INetFwMgr only exposes the global firewall settings.

The settings corresponding to the Control Panel Advanced tab are exposed by the INetSharingManager interface.

Apparently, I need to use both interfaces to know the complete firewall configuration.